# Weblate on Openshift: Failed to verify SSH host key (Neither with $GIT_SSH)

Tags: git, openshift, ssh-keys, weblate

we are trying to setup weblate 2.0 on openshift following the provided documentation
http://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/quick.html

We get stuck trying to clone the project from a private repo, after setting up the correct ssh_keys in the admin section, we still get

> Failed to verify SSH host key, please add them in SSH page in the admin interface.

We have exported GIT_SSH as enviroment variable (and create the command wrapper) like explained here

> https://forums.openshift.com/jenkins-stuff

But is working only if we ssh directly to the machine, not from the weblate interface.

Is there any way to explicitly set that ENV Variable for the owner of the process for which weblate is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is quite old question, but this issue have been fixed in Weblate 2.1, so upgrading Weblate should fix it. Weblate now handles GIT_SSH variable and automatically passes correct ssh keys and options to ssh.